# Check if get intent is null, insert 0 to column

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two flow in my android app activity.

> 1. A >> B >> C
> 2. A >> C

Activity C has a save button used to save the value pass from A and B.

**Activity C**

```
 weather = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Weather"); //pass from A
 date2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date2"); //pass from A
 status = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Status"); // pass from B
 Sub = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sub"); // pass from B

 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // sumbit button is clicked
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
           insertA(weather, date2);
           insertB(status,Sub,idA);
           insertC(food,idA);
            }
        });
```

**Noted that the idA is always same with Table A ID**

**Table A**

```
ID  Weather   date
1    sunny     1/6
2    rainy     2/6
```

**Table B**

```
ID    status   Sub   idA
1     work     2      1
2     work     1      2
```

**Table C**

```
ID    food    idA
1     rice      1
2    noodles    2
```

Data can be inserted correctly if it is from first flow. The problem now is when it is from second flow, there are nothing insert into table B including the IdA. How can I make it insert 0 in table B column, which are status and sub so that the idA can be inserted ?

Thanks.

**Table B**

I want something like this

**Table B**

```
ID    status   Sub   idA
1     0         0     1   // if it is from second flow
2     work      1     2
```

**Not this**

**Table B**    (When there has data inserted in second time)

```
ID    status   Sub   idA
1    work     1       2
```

Comment: Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: @Msp edited..have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second flow, status and Sub are not passed. So `getExtras()` is returning null for these values. That's why it's not getting added to database (maybe because of dabase design restrictions. Like a `not null`).

So, try changing your code like this,

```
status = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Status", "0"); 
Sub = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sub", "0");
```

Here, second parameter is the default value, which will be passed in case of null. In second flow "0" will be passed null.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for :D

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding.. :)